# How to parse a string into a decimal when the string is in the format $$$$$$$$cc in c#?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a string which is in this format  "$$$$$$$$cc" i.e. it doesent have a "."

could you please tell me how i could parse this into  a decimal easily.. ?

im using c#

Regards,
Prkash

Comment: What do '$' and 'c' represent?

Comment: Whatz this to do with datetime, can you please take some effort for asking this question .. its vague + weird

Answer (score 1):

you could just add the "." manually at the right place before parsing or parse it to a double then devide it by 100 which will get you $$$$$$,cc

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal myParse( string s )
{
  return
    decimal.Parse( s.Substring(0,s.Length-2) ) + 
    decimal.Parse( s.Substring(s.Length-2) ) / 100;
}
```